# Prevent flyTo within a leaflet in shiny from refreshing map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to add an `easyButton` with a `flyTo` function within a `shiny` app in `R`.

When the user presses the button, it will fly to the current location (lat/long). I am using a `reactivePoll` to poll a boat instrument simulator every 5 seconds ([NMEA simulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmea-simulator/dfhcgoinjchfcfnnkecjpjcnknlipcll?hl=en)), which is where the lat/long come from. A path is also drawn by using `addCircleMarkers`. I want to keep this path drawn, and the `flyTo` button to pan and zoom to the current location without refreshing the map, i.e. removing the path that was drawn.

In my current code with the `flyTo` button, with every poll the map refreshes. If I remove this code, the map does not refresh, so I think how I'm using the reactive within this button is the issue, but I'm not sure why. It may be because I have a reactive inside a reactive (`All_NMEA()` inside of `renderleaflet()`). The code of interest in the reprex is:

```
addEasyButton(easyButton(
        icon = "fa-crosshairs", title = "Locate Vessel",
        onClick = JS("
             function(btn, map) {
             map.flyTo([", paste(as.numeric(All_NMEA()["lat"]) / 100), ",", paste(as.numeric(All_NMEA()["long"]) / -100), "], zoom = 10);
             }
             ")
    ))
```

The NMEA simulator is required to produce data that is polled, linked above.
Reproducible example:

```
# https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmea-simulator/dfhcgoinjchfcfnnkecjpjcnknlipcll?hl=en
# needs an NMEA simulator to generate the poll data
#

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

connect <- function() {
    s_con <<- socketConnection("127.0.0.1", port = 55555, open = "a+")
    Sys.sleep(1)
    NMEA_poll <<- readLines(s_con, n = 18)
    close(s_con)
    return(NMEA_poll)

}

pollGPRMC <- function(data) {
    gps_ans <- list(rmc = NULL, rest = data)
    rxp <-
        "\\$GPRMC(,[^,]*){12}\\*[0-9,A-F]{2}"
    beg <- regexpr(rxp, data)
    if (beg == -1)
        return(gps_ans)
    end <-
        beg + attr(beg, "match.length")
    sub <-
        substr(data, beg, end - 6)
    gps_ans$rmc <-
        strsplit(sub, ",")[[1]]
    names(gps_ans$rmc) <- c(
        "id_rmc",
        "UTC",
        "status",
        "lat",
        "N/S",
        "long",
        "E/W",
        "boat speed (knots)",
        "cog (deg)",
        "date (ddmmyy)" # ddmmyy
    )
    gps_ans$rest <- substr(data, end, nchar(data))
    return(gps_ans)
}

map_data <- data.frame(lat = c(36.05, 36.25), lon = c(-132.13, -132.33))


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Map"),

    mainPanel(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
              leafletOutput("map"))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    All_NMEA <- shiny::reactivePoll(
        5000,
        session,
        checkFunc = Sys.time,
        valueFunc = function() {
                connect()

                NMEA_data <- toString(NMEA_poll)
                GPS_dat <- pollGPRMC(NMEA_data)

                lat_deg <- substr(GPS_dat$rmc["lat"], 1, 2)
                lat_mins <- substr(GPS_dat$rmc["lat"], 3, 9)
                lat_for_dist <- as.numeric(lat_deg) + (as.numeric(lat_mins) / 60)
                print(lat_for_dist)
                lon_deg <- substr(GPS_dat$rmc["long"], 1, 3)
                lon_mins <- substr(GPS_dat$rmc["long"], 4, 9)
                lon_for_dist <- (as.numeric(lon_deg) + (as.numeric(lon_mins) / 60))*-1
                print(lon_for_dist)


            leafletProxy("map", session = session) %>%
                addCircleMarkers(
                    lng = lon_for_dist,
                    lat = lat_for_dist,
                    radius = 1,
                    fillOpacity = 1, color = "red"
                )


            NMEA_out <- c(GPS_dat$rmc)

            return(NMEA_out)

        }
    )

    ord <- function(data) {
        print(data)
    }

    observe(ord(All_NMEA()))

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        map <- leaflet(map_data) %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.OceanBasemap, group = "ocean basemap (default)") %>%
            addTiles(group = "Basic") %>%
            fitBounds( ~ min(lon), ~ min(lat), ~ max(lon), ~ max(lat)) %>%
            addLayersControl(
                baseGroups = c("ocean basemap (default)", "Basic"),
                options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
                   fitBounds( ~ min(lon), ~ min(lat), ~ max(lon), ~ max(lat)) %>%
        addEasyButton(easyButton(
            icon = "fa-crosshairs", title = "Locate Vessel",
            onClick = JS("
                 function(btn, map) {
                 map.flyTo([", paste(as.numeric(All_NMEA()["lat"]) / 100), ",", paste(as.numeric(All_NMEA()["long"]) / -100), "], zoom = 10);
                 }
                 ")
        ))
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I have this error when I run your app: `Warning: Error in socketConnection: cannot open the connection`, is this something you can fix or is it specific to me?

Comment: Good question. I'm unsure if that would be a permission or network issue. Does that happen immediately, or after trying to connect for a bit?

Comment: it crashes the app immediately, as soon as it is run

Comment: Does changing "127.0.0.1" to "localhost" make a difference?

Comment: No, same problem

Comment: I'm not sure the "open" mode would matter, a+ is just to read and append. You could specify a port (e.g. 3434), and just make sure it's the same in the NMEA simulator. Apart from that, I'm still leaning to a file permission or network issue, but not sure how to fix. Thanks for trying to help with my question though.

Comment: Do I need to install some NMEA stuff or is it supposed to run just with your example?

Comment: It requires that NMEA simulator to generate data, but without it running it should at least open a shiny app with a blank window.

Comment: well your previous suggestion does not work either, maybe other people will be able to help you

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: i also get the error `Warnung in socketConnection("127.0.0.1", port = 55555, open = "a+")
  127.0.0.1:55555 cannot be opened`,... R 3.6.2, RStudio 1.3.935, shiny 1.4.0, Chrome 80.039...

Comment: That is really odd, I'm not sure what's going on. It works on both my home and work computers. Is it possibly a firewall denial?

Comment: Maybe ou ould simplify the app, without the need of creating a socket etc.. Just a random data poll.. But my guess is that you should use `leafletProxy` for the `addEasyButton`. Right now its in the `renderLeaflet` block, so whenever `All_NMEA()` updates, te map will be redrawn from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered the question yourself in your last sentence. The map will always be redrawn whenever the reactive `All_NMEA` changes. To prevent that, you would normally use `leafletProxy` but apparently you cannot add an `easyButton` like that, so I offer you another solution.

A click on the `easyButton` will trigger another shiny input that is called `my_easy_button`. In an `observeEvent` you listen to this event and do the `flyTo` there within a `leafletProxy`.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

map_data <- data.frame(lat = c(36.05, 36.25), lon = c(-132.13, -132.33))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Map"),
  mainPanel(tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
            leafletOutput("map"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  All_NMEA <- shiny::reactivePoll(
    intervalMillis = 5000,
    session = session,
    checkFunc = Sys.time,
    valueFunc = function() {
      NMEA_out <- data.frame(lat = runif(1, 0, 20),
                             long = runif(1, 0, 20))

      leafletProxy("map", session = session) %>%
        addCircleMarkers(
          lng = NMEA_out$long,
          lat = NMEA_out$lat,
          radius = 1,
          fillOpacity = 1, color = "red"
        )
      return(NMEA_out)
    }
  )
  observe({All_NMEA()})

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    map <- leaflet(map_data) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.OceanBasemap, group = "ocean basemap (default)") %>%
      addTiles(group = "Basic") %>%
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("ocean basemap (default)", "Basic"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>% 
      addEasyButton(
        easyButton(id = "buttonid",
                   icon = "fa-crosshairs", title = "Locate Vessel",
                   onClick = JS("function(btn, map) {
                                  Shiny.onInputChange('my_easy_button', 'clicked', {priority: 'event'});
                                }")
        ))
  })

  observeEvent(input$my_easy_button, {
    print("easyButton is clicked")
    allnmea <- req(All_NMEA())
    leafletProxy("map", session = session) %>%
      flyTo(lng = allnmea$long, lat = allnmea$lat, zoom = 5)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I could not find much at all for using an easy button like this. So anytime I want to use a reactive element on a map, it should go into a leafletProxy. And apparently I should learn how to use JS better with shiny.